# Why I can't understand the derivative (with example). Can someone help me understand?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The derivative of a function is said to be $\lim_{\Delta{x}\to 0} \frac{f(\Delta{x}+x)-f(x)}{\Delta{x}}$. This I believe I understand. But, I always have trouble believing something that is so theoretical without walking through a concrete example. So, I took the derivative of the function $f(x)=x^2+2x+4$ and I, of course, got $f'(x)=2x+2$. So, this says that for a marginal change in $x$, there will be a change in $y$ of $2(1)+2=4$.

I evaluate the original function at $x=1$ and I find that $y=7$. Then I evaluate the original function at $x=2$ and I find that $y=12$. In this case $\frac{\Delta{y}}{\Delta{x}}=5$, not the $4$ predicted by our derivative function. Where is the mistake in my thinking? Can someone provide me with a concrete example of the derivative that will show me that it does work?

Comment: Your understanding of a derivative is a bit off. The derivatives only says that marginal change is 4 when $\Delta x \to 0$. If you take values of $x$ much closer to 1, you will see that $\dfrac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ gets much closer to 4.

Comment: It is just the limit of the slopes of the secants.

Comment: Going from x=1 to x=2 is not a *marginal* change.  It's *huge* change.  Try it for $\Delta x $ is smaller. Say .01.  y then equals 1+.02+.0001+2.02 + 4=7.0401.  A difference of .0401.  The discepency is that even as we take a difference of .01 the function got steeper and the marginal rate of change got slightly larger.  You need to wrap your mind around the idea that calculus is about **INSTANTANEOUS** change.  Even a change of .01 is pretty large. A change of one is just plain out of the ballpark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{align*}
f'(1) &= \lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{f(\Delta x + 1) - f(1)}{\Delta x}\\
&=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{(\Delta x + 1)^{2} + 2(\Delta x + 1) + 4 - 7}{\Delta x}\\
&=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{(\Delta x)^{2} + 2\Delta x + 1 + 2\Delta x + 2 + 4 - 7}{\Delta x}\\
&=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{(\Delta x)^{2} + 4\Delta x}{\Delta x}\\
&=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\Delta x + 4\\
&=4. 
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You did the derivative right.  But graph the function (it's a parabola).  Now draw a tangent line at $x=1;y=7$.  Notice that at the very *instant* the tangent line touches the curve, both the function and the line are increasing, *at that moment*, at a rate (slope) of $4$.

But the parabola is not a straight line.  Even though it is increasing at a rate of 4 *at that point*, it is constantly "accelerating" and "pulls away from the tangent line and increases even faster.

That's what *marginal* change means; the rate of change at a moment.  The difference between $f (1) $ and $f (2) $ is $5$, which is only $25\% $ off what we expected. That's actually pretty good as going from $x=1$ to $x=2$ is ... a pretty large margin.

Try a smaller margin.  Say from $x=1$ to $x=1.01$.  Then the difference is $\frac {[(1.01)^2 + 2 (1.01)+4]-[1^2+2+4]}{.01}=\frac {[1.0201+2.02+4]-7}{.01}=\frac {.0401}{.01}=4.01$.

Even this small value isn't perfect (it's off by .25%).  Because the function is *constantly* changing and its rate change is constantly changing.